# Unable to use \thanks for one author

Tags: footnotes, titles, amsart

EDIT 2: My question was indeed a duplicate or otherwise clouded in some of my own misunderstanding.  Apologies for the inconvenience.

EDIT: This question was closed as a duplicate, but the thread linked does not solve my problem.  My issue is that I cannot put any sort of `\thanks`, `\footnote`, or even `\footnotemark` inside of the second argument of `\author`.  Also, I am not adding a URL.  I am adding text.

I am struggling to add a `\thanks` to the second author (which should go at the bottom of the first page).  In the following, the only thing that's missing is **(a)** a number/symbol for the second author, and **(b)** a number/symbol for the footer that `\thanks` creates.  Putting `thanks` inside the second author full name threw an error.  I also tried `\footnote`, but didn't manage to make it work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, amsfonts,color}

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}

\author[F. Author]{First Author}
\author[S. Author]{Second Author}\thanks{for all the fish}
\address{the department\\
a place}
\email[F. Author]{fauthor@theschool.edu} 
\email[S. Author]{sauthor@theschool.edu}



\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
the abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{intro}
lots of good stuff 

\end{document}
```

[image: output of the above code]

Hopefully this is easy to solve.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `amsart` treats `\thanks` as an unnumbered footnote.  This is a design decision.  To identify the specific author, enter it as `\thanks{The second author says, thanks for all the fish.}`

Comment: @barbarabeeton This did not solve the problem and I explicitly stated this in my question.  I cannot use ```\thanks``` within the second argument of ```\author```.  The problem seems to be that I literally cannot put any kind of ```\thanks```, ```\footnote```, or ```\footnotemark``` inside the second argument of ```\author```.

Comment: My apologies. I did a poor job reading your reply and responding. I understand what you and @KJO were saying better now.

Comment: The problem with the code you show in this question is that the `\thanks` *cannot* be nested within an argument of `\author`; it *must* be a separate element at the same level as `\author`, and with `amsart`, it will be carried with (and internally numbered the same as) the `\author` element it follows.  All the same, it's best to include text identifying *which* author is involved, as `\thanks{The second author ...)`.  (And, apology accepted.  Although this isn't rocket science, it *can* be confusing if you're looking at it for the first time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be desirable to identify exactly which author was given a specific grant or is thanking their sponsor. It may be more diplomatic to Say

The Authors would both like to thank AMS for their generous support of this published article

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart} % A-M-S-ART-icle 
% Templates and template classes are built with ONE prime
% purpose, that is they serve to provide a like it or not framework. 
% ``As author, you are responsible for the content of your paper. 
% At the production end, the concern is to turn the (electronic)
% manuscript into a published document in the style of the designated journal
% see http: //mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf

% Unmarked, unnumbered footnotes on the ﬁrst page of an article should include
% primary classiﬁcation numbers according to the 2010 Mathematics Subject 
% Classiﬁcation scheme (www.ams.org/msc) (required);  grant information (optional);
% and key words and phrases describing the subject matter of the article (optional). 

% Formatting is automatic when using the AMS style ﬁles. 

% That framework may be upset by the use of package
% contents in a different order or subsequent changes
% to that envisioned by the template writers at the time.
% Item sequencing or structure should not be changed.
% to check what can be here and in what order consult
% the documentation. If you add an item to a template 
% it is your responsibility to change one item at a time
% for comparability.
\usepackage{lipsum} % for demonstration only 

\begin{document} % Be aware this document is invalid it does not follow class rules

%main data block
%%
%% The title of the paper goes here.  Edit to your title.
%%
\title[short]{A duplicate question} % longtitle data to be placed at start
%%
%% Now edit the following to give first name and address:
%% Also you can Give information on grants or contracts under which the research
%% was performed, including grant number, using the \thanks command. 
%% 
\author{I'm First Author} % author sign off to be placed at article closing is a fixed sequence
\address{At the department, some plaice\vspace{0.3cm}} % A one line SC entry 
\email{foo@theschool.edu}% Italics then bold
\thanks{Thanks... @ barbara beeton ... for all her hard work as TeX ``champion'' at AMS} % the first authors thanks data is collected from any first occurrence
%%
%% If there is a secondary author edit the following.
%%
\author{ALSO Second Author}
%\address{ALSO At the department, some plaice} % IF required for a second establishment
\email{ALSO bar@theschool.edu}% Italics then bold
% Second authors thanks data is collected from the correct placement of defining 2nd \thanks
\thanks{ALSO Thanks to @ sigma-finite for a generous grant of ``If at first it does not work ... lets describe it''}
%%%
%%% The following is for the abstract.  The abstract is optional and
%%% if not used just delete, or comment out, the following.
%%%
%\begin{abstract}% Environment data for Title abstract data on first page
%The abstract is defined before the maketitle command is invoked
%\end{abstract}
%%
%%  LaTeX will not make the title for the paper unless told to do so.
%%  This is done by uncommenting the following.
%%
\maketitle % For amsArt(icle) class maketitle function should appear after above data is loaded including abstract


\section{How AMS article class works}

We can see the AMS Class is not expecting any data in the \bf first page footing \normalfont other than mandatory classification such as \bf 15-06 Proceedings, conferences, collections, etc. or optional thanks for grants \normalfont or other abstract key words\\\par Lots of good floating stuff \hfill \lipsum [1-2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution in this case seems to be adding the author symbols manually:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, amsfonts,color}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\thankssymb[1]{\textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol{#1}}}
%\newcommand\thankssymb[1]{\lowercase{\textsuperscript{\@alph{#1}}}}
%\newcommand\thankssymb[1]{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{A paper}

\author[F. Author]{First Author\thankssymb{1}}
\author[S. Author]{Second Author\thankssymb{2}}
\thanks{\thankssymb{1} for all the fish}
\thanks{\thankssymb{2} for all the chips}

\address{the department\\
a place}
\email[F. Author]{fauthor@theschool.edu} 
\email[S. Author]{sauthor@theschool.edu}

\begin{abstract}
the abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{intro}
lots of good stuff 

\end{document}
```

> [image]

I defined a new command `\thankssymb` that takes a number as first argument, representing the author to be referenced and to be used in `\author` and `\thanks`.

Three example styles for `\thankssymb` are given for footnote symbols, lowercase letters and plain numbers, respectively. Note the use of `lowercase` inside the second variant, as the author names are typeset in uppercase letters in `amsart`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a "simpler" work around:

```
\author{First Author^1} \thanks{^1 Thanks\ for\ releasing\ fish}
```

The backslashes are need to keep the spaces in - dont know why.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This might be a workaround, but the ``^`` for superscripts works only in math mode, so this code is going to cause many errors.